# Generate random point on a 2D disk in 3D space given normal vector

Tags: math, random, 3d, geometry, linear-algebra

Is there a simple and efficient method to generate a random (uniformly distributed) point on a disk "hanging" in 3-dimensional space? The disk is defined by its normal.

Ideally, I would like to avoid rotation matrices, as I do not fully understand them, and I know they have issues.

So far, I've tried generating a 3D unit vector and projecting it onto the plane of the disk, which does ensure that the point is within the disk, but not that it's uniformly distributed.
 I also tried scaling the generated vector according to some function of its length, but I couldn't get a uniform distribution back regardless.

I had an idea that involved creating 2 vectors perpendicular to each other and the normal, to define a local coordinate system. Then I could generate a point on the unit disk as in 2D and convert the result back to the global coordinate system. This seems like it would be quite efficient, as it involves some precomputation (which I'm completely fine with) and only simple calculations afterwards (this is for a raytracer, so it'll happen a lot). The problem is, I don't know how to reliably calculate the local coordinate system's basis vectors while avoiding possible issues like collinearity.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A easy way to calculate orthogonal basis vectors u, v for a plane with normal n = (a,b,c) is finding the component with least absolute value, and making u orthogonal to that component; the rest pretty much follows. For example, if the first component is the one with minimal absolute value, you can pick these basis vectors:

```
u = (0, -c, b)                //  n·u = -bc+cb = 0

v = (b²+c², -ab, -ac)         //  n·v = ab²+ac²-ab²-ac² = 0, u·v = abc-abc = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that just about fixes my problems. To clarify, the component of `u` I need to set to `0` is the one that's maximal in `n`, is that correct? Does it follow that, for every 3-vector, there exists at least one (two?) corresponding orthogonal vector that is parallel to one of the 3 planes defined by the axes of the system (and therefore one of its components is 0)?

Comment: Yes it does: The normal vector defines a plane, and any two planes are either parallel or cross along a line. Any vector on the line of intersection is parallel to both planes.

Comment: Wait a minute... check the update, what I had written would break for n = (1,0,0) for example, as it would compute u = v = (0,0,0). You should choose the *minimal* component.

Comment: Good catch! Is this method continous, that is, can I rely on it to not suddenly "flip" one of the basis vectors as the normal vector is being rotated?

Comment: It's not continuous, and it's impossible to make it completely continuous because the choice of basis would depend on the path that has been traveled and not only on the normal vector.

Comment: Depend on the path? Do you mean something like the Frenet-Serret frame? Is it definitely completely impossible to do this continously, as a function of the normal vector alone?

Comment: I mean the rotations that you made to get the normal vector where it is. Think about facing north and raising your right arm: your sight pointing north and your left shoulder pointing west define the normal vectors to the up direction. Now imagine if you had been facing east originally: the normal vectors to "up" would then be east and north. So which should be the basis corresponding to "up", (west,north) or (north,east)? It can't be both...

Comment: The fact that you can never make the function continuous no matter how you tweak it is not obvious at all, but it is a corollary of the ["Hairy ball" theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39142/discussion-between-more-axes-and-joni)

Comment: Am I the only one who is somewhat confused by this explanation? By "the component with least absolute value", I take it you mean a scalar that is part of *n*, that is, either *a*, *b*, or *c*. But then, how can *u* be orthogonal to that component? How can a *vector* be *orthogonal* to a *scalar*? Or is this a piece of mathematical terminology I am unfamiliar with?

Comment: By "orthogonal to that component" I mean orthogonal to the component's direction, i.e. if you pick the first component, orthogonal to (1,0,0), if you pick the second, orthogonal to (0,1,0), etc